# PHP Description Excerpt

Tags: php, echo

I have the following code and need it to only echo out 100 words or less in the description rather than the entire description. Is there anyway to do that by editing this code?

```
public static function getExcerpt($profile) {
    $out='';
    if(!empty($profile['description'])) {
        $out.=$profile['description'].' '.__('', 'lovestory');
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sure there is. I suggest you take a look at the php documentation, specifically the string search functions: you are looking for a way to search for the 100th occurance of a whitespace character in a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// for 100 characters...
if (strlen($profile['description']) > 100)
    $description = substr($profile['description'], 0, 100) . "...";
else
    $description = $profile['description'];

$out.= $description . ' ' . __('', 'lovestory');


// for 100 words
$out.= implode(" ", array_slice(explode(" ", $profile['description']), 0, 100)) .' '.__('', 'lovestory');
```

Comment: That will only output the first 100 characters surely?

Comment: Yes it will output first 100 characters only, Do you want first 100 words ?? If yes, then Just explode it with " " (space) and implode only first hundreds with space.

Comment: Yeah it said 'words' in his question :D

Comment: That's perfect thanks so much. Is it possible to add dots at the end, i.e. "..." after the first 100 words has been reached? In other words to show that their description is longer when you click on their link. I've added the dots but it adds them to all the profiles and some of them have descriptions under 100 words. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Sorry I meant first 100 characters. :D

Comment: Lol ... Yeah just use substr like he said in the first place ... Then use `$out.= ' ...'` afterwards

Comment: That adds the dots to all user profiles. I only need the dots for user profiles that extend past 100 characters. Any solutions?

Comment: Nice one!! Thank you very much for your pro-skills in helping me solve this! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use PHP's wordwrap function as shown below.

```
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$newText = wordwrap(substr($text, 0, 20), 19, '...');
echo $newText;
```

will print `The quick brown fox...`

Comment: How would i get these dots at the end of a description that contains more than 100 characters?

Comment: @user2382274 Replace 20 with 100 and 19 with 99 in above functions.

Comment: Wait this is how it came out - Hi Students, I am available to mentor you in Physics, Chemistry and Maths and postgraduate...studie

Comment: put your string inside wordwrap(substr('your text here', 0, 100), 99, '...') function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode with an empty space to create an array of words, and if there are more than 100 words, use array_slice to select the first 100, then implode that array back into a string

```
$words = explode(' ', $out);
if(count($words) > 100){
    return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, 100));
else{
    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how exact you want to be or how complicated your word boundaries are, but in general something like this would work for you:

```
$excerpt = explode(' ', $profile['description']);
$excerpt = array_slice($excerpt, 0, 100);
$out .= implode(' ', $excerpt).' '.__('', 'lovestory');
```